# Why the custom separator view in the cell changes height?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, custom-view

I have custom tableViewCell. And in it cell i have custom separator. The logic of work should be like this:

1. if select textField in cell - separator change color and
   height(from 1 to 2)
2. if type text - separator color and height not
   change

Now it's work like:

1. if not added constrain for height for separator in .xib - added constrain for height when create cell, but in screen it equal 0

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    customSeparator.backgroundColor = .lightGray
    customSeparator.frame.size.height = 1.0
}
```

2. if added constrain for height for separator in .xib - when select cell height of separator change(like expected). But when type text height change to value specified in .xib

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    customSeparator.backgroundColor = .black
    customSeparator.frame.size.height = 2.0       
}
```

So, why is this happening, tell me, plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an height IBOutlet constraint and change it as follows:

```
@IBOutlet weak var customSeparatorHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    customSeparator.backgroundColor = .lightGray
    customSeparatorHeight.constant = 1
    self.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```